# Oozie specialized actions vs generic action

Tags: hadoop, oozie

Oozie offers several specialized actions such as Spark action, Hive action, and HDFS action. From a design perspective, would it be better use these specialized actions or to build a generic framework in a language such as Java / Scala and always use the Java action? A generic framework would be agile to changes (e.g., if I decide to swap out Spark in favor of a better library in the future, I can simply change the framework code and not all my previous usecases to use the new library). However, it does restrict all developers in the team to only the Java action, despite all the other convenient actions offered by Oozie.

What would be the best course of action?

Comment: Do you fully understand how Oozie bootstraps a YARN job using a "launcher" mapper, how Oozie manages dependencies (cf. ShareLibs), how Oozie manages authentication (proxy user for impersonation + Hadoop delegation tokens + special `credentials` for Hive etc. using Kerberos), etc ?

Comment: Yes, yes and yes. We would still be using Oozie; only that we would always use only the Java action that would then use the classes in our framework. Since every Hadoop related library has a Java API, these classes would implement all functionality in Java code. In the future, if anything changes in the Hadoop ecosystem, we need only to change our framework that is used by *all* workflows, rather than all previous workflows.

Comment: Did you also consider alternatives to Oozie (Airflow etc.) which may be easier to "bend" for your framework usage? Honestly, some people hate Oozie, most avoid it carefully, but very few love it...